# Executing this PHP program?

Tags: javascript, php

I am not able to get this program working. I'm sure I have all the correct syntax, brackets etc... However, it just spits out code that is put into it, am I missing anything?

The program should post upon itself from the post method, after executing a JavaScript program.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="EN" dir="ltr" xmin="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/xml; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Site.php</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myform" method="Post" action="Site.php">
            <center><table><tr>
                        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="mo" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['mo']; ?>" size="4"/></td>
                        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="dy" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['dy']; ?>" size="4"/></td>
                        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="yr" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['yr']; ?>" size="4"/></td>
                        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="hr" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['hr']; ?>" size="4"/></td>
                        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="mn" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['mn']; ?>" size="4"/></td>
                        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="sc" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['sc']; ?>" size="4"/></td>
                    </tr</table></center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
$mo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "mo");
$dy = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "dy");
$yr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "yr");
$hr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "hr");
$mn = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "mn");
$sc = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "sc");

session_start();

$_SESSION['mo'] = $mo;
$_SESSION['dy'] = $dy;
$_SESSION['yr'] = $yr;
$_SESSION['hr'] = $hr;
$_SESSION['mn'] = $mn;
$_SESSION['sc'] = $sc;
$_SESSION['count'] = $count;

session_write_close();
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean that it just outputs the actual PHP code? If so, perhaps PHP isn't installed on the server, or the server isn't set to invoke PHP for .php files.

Comment: Is your PHP code before the HTML?

Comment: put php code before form

Comment: how do you submit your form ? without at least submit button ? how do you expect that the data will be submitted without submission ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 . Take your session_start() to the top of your page.

2 . validate your count variable as it doesn't exists.. may be you are loading it from somewhere else, do this `isset($count) ? $count : "";`

3 . Add a submit button to your form in order to store data in your session.